# This PyCharm warning does not make sense to me

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Please take a look at the following line of code:

```
self.supervisees = [] if supervisees is None else self.supervisees = supervisees
```

for some reason the second instance of the local variable supervisees (directly after if), when highlighted, gives a warning:

"Local variable 'supervisees' value is not used... This inspection highlights local variables,parameters or local functions used in scope."

Can someone please explain why PyCharm is throwing this warning?

For more context on how the line fits into the class:

```
class Manager(Employee):
  raise_amount = 1.04

  """
  Alternative constructor, built to create
  Employee objects from strings.
  """

  @classmethod
  def from_string(cls, employee_string):
    first_name, last_name, id, salary, supervisees = employee_string.split('-', 1)
    return cls(first_name, last_name, id, salary, supervisees)

  def __init__(self, id, first_name, last_name, salary, supervisees = None):
    super().__init__(id, first_name, last_name, salary)

    self.supervisees = [] if supervisees is None else self.supervisees = supervisees

  """
  Add an employee to the managers
  employee supervision list.
  """

  def add_supervisees(self, employee):
    if employee not in self.supervisees:
      self.supervisees.append(employee)
      employee.set_manager(self)

  """
  Remove an employee from the managers
  employee supervision list.
  """

  def remove_supervisees(self, employee):
    self.supervisees.remove(employee)


def print_supervisees(self):
  return ', '.join(emp.full_name for emp in self.supervisees)
```

Comment: the syntax should be `self.supervisees = [] if supervisees is None else supervisees`

Comment: @ PRMoureu Thanks!